# Laravel customize rules by another fields

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-validation

I want to add validate a field depending on another field like:

`pay_time` => "required",

`"months" => "rules:pay_time"`

When pay_time is monthly, months is 1,2,3,4,.... but if pay_time is annual, months should be 12,24,36,...

How could I pass the pay_time value to extending validating function?

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-where-to-add-custom-validation-function  check the link for custom validation rule

Answer (score 0):

I think the better way to add the yearly values with another field with other name, then you can use `required_if` rule to validate it.

```
[ 
   pay_time => "required|in:monthly,yearly",
   months => "required_if:pay_time,monthly|in:1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11",
   years => "required_if:pay_time,yearly|in:12,24,36,48",
]
```